# Add Webster Dictionary to my iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, books, dictionary

I am not a big fan of the Oxford dictionary. I am used to using the American Webster dictionary.

I have an iPad Pro, and I am using Apple Books app. Under Settings app → General → Dictionary, I am not able to add additional resources. I was able to download the Webster dictionary app from the App Store. Yet the dictionary was not added to the list in the Settings of my iPad.

How do I make the Webster dictionary database available under system dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to accompanist is not possible due to nature of how iOS works.

The list of dictionaries available under Settings app → General → Dictionary is curated by Apple, and can not be altered/added-to by end users.

If you download a dictionary app from the App Store, it does not, and cannot be automatically integrated into the iOS operating system and made available system wide.

To use the Webster dictionary, in your case, you'll have to manually type/copy the word into the app and determine the meaning.